Skipping locked rows when deleting data in SQL Server
I got a table in an ERP system where lot of old data resides. I got a job which detects and deletes that outdated data.
However, some of that data is locked by the ERP system and therefore cannot be deleted. Unfortunately my delete job is waiting ages before that data eventually gets unlocked.
I tried to write an delete statement which skips those locked records, but with no success. I tried NOLOCK and READPAST hints, but they did not work. The delete statement still was blocked.
Is there any hint or other means available to perform this?

Are these rows that are locked also in scope for deletion?

yes, they are, but it's fine to skip them.

@ThomA Why wouldn't READPAST work?

It sounds like your ERP system isn't great. It's a bad idea to hold database locks for too long. Instead it should have been using some kind of optimistic locking/concurrency control.

Because my brain is already in holiday mode, @Charlieface . :)

OK READPAST should have worked, if it hasn't then you need to give a [mcve] showing what's going on.

I agree with @Charlieface, READPAST should work. I just gave it a go, and it works fine; note the first DELETE deletes 2 rows and the second 1, and ID 3 was locked when the first DELETE ran.

Ok, here's the example of this to make it more clear:
BEGIN TRY
DELETE FROM ConnectionInformation WITH(READPAST)
WHERE       ConnectionID IN (SELECT ConnectionID
FROM   @SessionTab)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
-- just ignore this
END CATCH
I tried NOLOCK and NOWAIT hints as well. It always gets locked on the DELETE statement. This code resides in a stored procedure which is called from a job running as 'sa'. In @SessionTab there are just a few records (< 10).

OK when it gets blocked can you run in a separate window this script which will tell what locks are blocking you https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2020/04/20/sql-server-blocking-tree-identifying-blocking-chain-using-sql-scripts/ I'm guessing you are seeing a Sch-M lock which I don't think can be avoided using READPAST. If so the next question is what's causing it, probably an index rebuild or statistics update, both of which can be changed to not block.

There is not much of a way, as Thom A mentions in comment, it's not how SQL Server works. There are ways to check if a table has locks inside of it, but not the individual rows to my knowledge.
You could attack this a couple ways, and perhaps even intertwine the approaches.
One way would be to try and delete from the table. Something to the effect of:
DECLARE @MaxRetries INT = 5;
DECLARE @RetryCount INT = 0;
DECLARE @WaitTime INT = 10; -- seconds

WHILE @RetryCount < @MaxRetries
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        -- Attempt the delete operation
        DELETE FROM YourTable
        WHERE YourCondition;

        -- Exit the loop if successful
        BREAK;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        -- Handle lock exception or log it
        IF ERROR_NUMBER() IN (1205, 1222) -- Error numbers for deadlocks and lock timeouts
        BEGIN
            SET @RetryCount = @RetryCount + 1;
            WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:' + CAST(@WaitTime AS VARCHAR(2));
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            -- Rethrow the exception if it's not a lock error
            THROW;
        END
    END CATCH
END

Another thing to look into:
 SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY { LOW | NORMAL | HIGH | <numeric-priority> } 

This could be dangerous though as I have 0 knowledge of your system and the reason the locks are occurring. There is potential that other process causing locks are set to HIGH priority here, and maybe for good reason.

Thank you for your answer. I already tried 'TRY .. CATCH', but this does not prevent to get locked. In addition I used the NOWAIT hint in the DELETE statement to not to wait for the record, but somehow it did not work.
